# How to convert String Object from socket to Key, Value pair in Javascript and display on html

Tags: javascript, arrays, sockets, websocket, telnet

Using webtcp i build a bridge between socket and websocket and can get data from a machine and display it on browser. But this data is raw and needs to be parsed. I was able to parse it up until array object but there was no further success. Whatever i do it just returns as an object.
Below is the initial raw data from socket:

```
received: 2018-08-13T16:43:34.0689|power|ON|mode|MANUAL|execution|READY|Xact|0.00|Yact|0.00|Zact|0.00|Xcom|0.00|Ycom|0.00|Zcom|0.00|path_feedrate|0.00|line|0|Block|0|program|O-Logo.ord

received: 2018-08-13T16:43:34.0689|comms|NORMAL||||
2018-08-13T16:43:34.0689|Sspeed|0.00
```

then i removed timestamp and turned it to an array by doing:

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    var machineData = data.split("|");
    var arrData = machineData.slice(1);
    console.log("received: " + arrData);
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = ("Received: " + arrData);
});
```

and i get this:

```
received: power,ON,mode,MANUAL,execution,READY,Xact,0.00,Yact,0.00,Zact,0.00,Xcom,0.00,Ycom,0.00,Zcom,0.00,path_feedrate,0.00,line,0,Block,0,program,O-Logo.ord

received: comms,NORMAL,,,,
2018-08-13T16:47:40.0978,Sspeed,0.00
```

Unfortunately i can not parse it further, i tried so many methods and all i get was Object:object. I want this data to be key:value pairs, like

```
power:ON
mode: MANUAL
execution: READY
```

and so on and without any timestamps. This data is dynamic and it will change as machine is working. I tried most of the methods posted here and there but always it would just return Object with no data. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var str = "power|ON|mode|MANUAL|execution|READY|Xact|0.00|Yact|0.00|Zact|0.00|Xcom|0.00|Ycom|0.00|Zcom|0.00|path_feedrate|0.00|line|0|Block|0|program|O-Logo.ord";

var arr = str.split("|");

var obj = {}

arr.map((o, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0) obj[o] = arr[i + 1];
})

console.log(obj)
```

In your code you should do something like:

```
socket.on("data", function(data) {
  var arr = data.split("|").slice(1);

  var obj = {};

  arr.map((o, i) => {
    if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0) obj[o] = arr[i + 1];
  });

  console.log(obj);
})
```

If you want to put inside html, here a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/p5d7f3Lx/

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, this is what i got back:                                           [object Object]
socket_client.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at Socket.ondataCustom (socket_client.html:59)
    at Socket.WebTCPIO.onEvent (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:1356)
    at e.WebTCP.sock.onmessage (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:1339)
    at e.p.dispatchEvent (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:172)
    at e._dispatchMessage (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:694)
    at e._didMessage (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:722)
    at WebSocket.f.ws.onmessage (webtcp-0.0.1.min.js:780)

Comment: this is what i get each time. I tried so many methods and all i get will be this: received: [object Object]

Comment: yes i tried both of them. console.log(data) i get just string data: 2018-08-13T18:09:07.0760|power|ON|mode|MANUAL|execution|READY|Xact|0.00|Yact|0.00|Zact|0.00|Xcom|0.00|Ycom|0.00|Zcom|0.00|path_feedrate|0.00|line|0|Block|0|program|O-Logo.ord

Comment: as you see i added JSON.stringify but the result got parsed again to received: [object Object]. It is so weird. I can stringify and i can .split and .slice but i can't make it key value pairs...

Comment: @Asyl If you are able to split and slice you are parsing the result, maybe the error is in other place nothing to do with this place, where is line 59?

Comment: there is nothing except getting live string data from a socket, which is not parsing further to key value pairs. And I am stuck with this problem last three days((

Comment: @Asyl Don't worry, do again console.log(data) and take a screenshot of the console and upload the image somewhere and paste the link.

Comment: thank you for your help. the mistake was stupid. I did not know that if in console.log i put string before object it turns my object into sting and just outputs object object. i should just output only obj.

Comment: Could you please explain this: arr.map((o, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0) obj[o] = arr[i + 1];
}); Million thanks. one last question, how would i dynamically output my data to html now?

Comment: @Asyl great! .map iterate over the array, "o" means each element, and "i" means the index of such element.  the % is the module, so we try to find even indexes (divisible by 2) in such a case we assign the property "o" and the value arr[I+1] (the next element), reduce is basically the same. I've used arrow notation, but it's almost the same as function (o,i){}. To put into html you could adapt the jsfiddle link I put in the answer. In that case I made a table, but you could show the information in other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic scenario for [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), converting the string into a flat array, and with the reduce you building the obj, just skipping every 2 items.

```js
const str = "power|ON|mode|MANUAL|execution|READY|Xact|0.00|Yact|0.00|Zact|0.00|Xcom|0.00|Ycom|0.00|Zcom|0.00|path_feedrate|0.00|line|0|Block|0|program|O-Logo.ord";

const arr = str.split("|");

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, current, i, original) => {
  if (i % 2 === 1) {
    acc[original[i - 1]] = current;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: i am just getting this: [object Object]. why it is not parsing string object to anything what i try...

Comment: thank you. i fixed my error. it was in outputing with string

Comment: how can i output this to html?

Comment: You can just use `JSON.stringify` on the object, that will return to u a string, that you will be able to put inside html.

Comment: `document.getElementById('element-id').innerText = JSON.stringify(obj);`